# Magento- 404 when passing a redirect address whilst using urlencode

Tags: php, magento, urlencode

In Magento, I have a controller that I am referencing in a few different spots. After the controller does it's action, it should redirect.

Now, I want to pass the redirect address as a parameter, but when I pass it through the address, I get a 404 error.

I am using urlencode, so the URL for example comes out as:

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin/operation/queueOrder/key/254f49caee2cc6e7533a92d45b48b24a/order_ids/[13]/redirect/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmagento%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2Fsales_order%2Fview%2Forder_id%2F13%2Fkey%2F1c5b6eb03a3d81f5286e8b15f11342fe%2F
```

If I take away the `redirect` parameter, it works.

My questions are:
1. Am I going the right way about this? Is there a better way to pass the redirect address?
2. Why do I get a 404? I am using `urlencode` on the redirect url

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with apache not magento. The apache server answers with a 404 page when encountering encoded slashes. It is disabled for security reasons and can be enabled using the AllowEncodedSlashes directive. I would recommend replacing the slashes instead.